# How to add array in complex multidimansional array in exact subarray if existis or not with unknow depth in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sub-array

Here is my problem. I have an complicated multidimensional array with different depths. Everything on Stackoverflow I tried, failed. I tried with array_push, array_merge, array_combined, foreach, for etc. Code I have is BS.

The array (part of it (has 15k records) you can find it [here](http://unstoppable-sports.de/schnittstelle/array.txt).

My goal is to find the last array and add an extra array.

The array what I am seeking in that multidimensional array is:

```
[Branch] => Array
           (
           [Branchno] => 000
           [Stockqty] => 1
           [Saleprice] => 119.95
           [Xprice] => 0
           [Qprice] => 54.85
           [NOS] => 0
           )
```

When I found this array, I need to add this array with no values:

```
[Order] => Array
           (
           [Deliverydate] =>
           [Orderqty] =>
           )
```

After this the array should like this:

```
[Branch] => Array
           (
           [Branchno] => 000
           [Stockqty] => 1
           [Saleprice] => 119.95
           [Xprice] => 0
           [Qprice] => 54.85
           [NOS] => 0
           [Order] => Array
                      (
                      [Deliverydate] =>
                      [Orderqty] =>
                      )
           )
```

The problem is: in that array, I could have an subarray like this:

```
[Branch] => Array
            (
                 [0] => Array
                        (
                        [Branchno] => 000
                        [Stockqty] => -4
                        [Saleprice] => 119.95
                        [Xprice] => 0
                        [Qprice] => 54.85
                        [NOS] => 0
                        )

                 [1] => Array
                        (
                        [Branchno] => 001
                        [Stockqty] => 4
                        [Saleprice] => 119.95
                        [Xprice] => 0
                        [Qprice] => 54.85
                        [NOS] => 0
                        )

             )
```

And i need to add the same array into those arrays. So, the array should look like this:

```
[Branch] => Array
            (
                 [0] => Array
                        (
                        [Branchno] => 000
                        [Stockqty] => -4
                        [Saleprice] => 119.95
                        [Xprice] => 0
                        [Qprice] => 54.85
                        [NOS] => 0
                        [Order] => Array
                                   (
                                   [Deliverydate] =>
                                   [Orderqty] =>
                                   )
                        )

                 [1] => Array
                        (
                        [Branchno] => 001
                        [Stockqty] => 4
                        [Saleprice] => 119.95
                        [Xprice] => 0
                        [Qprice] => 54.85
                        [NOS] => 0
                        [Order] => Array
                                   (
                                   [Deliverydate] =>
                                   [Orderqty] =>
                                   )
                        )

             )
```

Extra problem is, that some of those array could have the array what i want to add, with filled data and I need skip it. Like this:

```
[Branch] => Array
           (
           [Branchno] => 000
           [Stockqty] => 1
           [Saleprice] => 119.95
           [Xprice] => 0
           [Qprice] => 54.85
           [NOS] => 0
           [Order] => Array
                      (
                      [Deliverydate] => 20060911
                      [Orderqty] => 8
                      )
           )
```

Or like this:

```
[Branch] => Array
            (
                 [0] => Array
                        (
                        [Branchno] => 000
                        [Stockqty] => -4
                        [Saleprice] => 119.95
                        [Xprice] => 0
                        [Qprice] => 54.85
                        [NOS] => 0
                        )

                 [1] => Array
                        (
                        [Branchno] => 001
                        [Stockqty] => 4
                        [Saleprice] => 119.95
                        [Xprice] => 0
                        [Qprice] => 54.85
                        [NOS] => 0
                        [Order] => Array
                                   (
                                   [Deliverydate] => 20060911
                                   [Orderqty] => 8
                                   )
                        )

             )
```

Basicly, (pseudo code) i need to check every subarray (don't know how deep), check if the ORDER array exists (after [NOS])

if array Order exists = No,
    add array with no data

if array Order exists = Yes,
    look if the Order array has subarray, 
      if not, skip it (data present)

else

loop through array
     if Order array exists = yes, skip it (data present)

else

add array Order with no data

I don't know how to reach the last array to check, add or skip.

Comment: is there any to help me out?